# Plagiarism Detector Issue

Tags: java

Alright so the criteria for this code is that if the words found in string are found 90% of the time in string 2, and if the words in string 2 are found 90% of the time in string 1, then the boolean should be true and it should say that plagiarism has occured. The code is below;

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PlagiarismDetector
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("What file is the first file?");
 String fileOne = reader.next();

 String stringOne = readStringFromFile(fileOne);

 System.out.println("What file is the second file?");
 String fileTwo = reader.next();
 String stringTwo = readStringFromFile(fileTwo);

 if (stringOne == null || stringTwo == null)
 {
     return;
 }

 System.out.println("Comparing the 2 files......");
 System.out.println("The result of the 2 files is ....");

 if (compareStrings(stringOne, stringTwo))
 {
  System.out.println("Plagiarism detected. Cheaters!!!!");
 }
 else
 {
       System.out.println("No plagiarism detected");
       }
    }

    public static String readStringFromFile(String filename)
    {
 String builder = "";
 try
 {
     Scanner fileReader = new Scanner(new File(filename));
     while (fileReader.hasNextLine())
     {
  builder = builder + fileReader.nextLine() + "\n";
     }

     return builder;
 }
 catch (Exception e)
 {
     System.out.println("An error occurred while trying to open the file " + filename + ". Is the file located inside the same folder as the .class file and with the identical name?");
     return null;
 }
    }

     public static boolean compareStrings (String a, String b)
 {
   boolean checkForPlagiarism = true;
   String[] piecesA = a.split("\\s");
   String[] piecesB = b.split("\\s");

   double count1 = 0.0;
   double count2 = 0.0;
   for (int counter = 0; counter < piecesA.length; counter++)
    {
      for(int counter2 = 0; counter < piecesB.length; counter2++)
      {
          if(piecesA[counter].equals(piecesB[counter2]))
          {
          count1++;
          }
      }
    }
   for (int counter = 0; counter < piecesB.length; counter++)
    {
      for(int counter2 = 0; counter < piecesA.length; counter2++)
      {
          if(piecesA[counter2].equals(piecesB[counter]))
          {
          count2++;
          }
      }
    }

   if((count1/piecesA.length) >= 0.9 && (count2/piecesB.length) >= 0.9)
   {
     checkForPlagiarism = true;
   }    
    return checkForPlagiarism;
  }
}
```

I'm getting this error message however which i havent been able to debug;

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
at PlagiarismDetector.compareStrings(PlagiarismDetector.java:67)
at PlagiarismDetector.main(PlagiarismDetector.java:24)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Any help would be deeply appreciated guys.

Comment: Is this a different issue than the one you posted earlier?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194877/plagiarism-detector . If so why cant you apply learning from that post?

Comment: Seems to be the same code. @OP don't create new accounts to post new questions.

Comment: Not *completely* the same. The ending conditions in the for loop are different (As was suggested in answers of the other question).

Comment: @user000001 Close enough to make my plagiarism detector go off ;)

Answer (score 2):

`for(int counter2 = 0; counter < piecesB.length; counter2++)`

should probably be

`for(int counter2 = 0; counter2 < piecesB.length; counter2++)`